# How to implement borrow/copy for enums in rust

Tags: rust

I am creating a toy programming language using rust at https://github.com/ayushashi11/lang.
In my project in file src/executor.rs at line 12, the compiler says

```
use of moved value: `self.prog` 
move occured because self has type executor::Executor which doesn't implement the `Copy` trait.
```

I cant use the copy trait on Executor as its property prog has type token::Stmt which doesn't implement copy trait. I cant implement copy trait on Stmt because it has a property with String datatype which doesn't implement copy trait. I have tried implementing borrow trait using derive but it says it cant find macro for Borrow trait.

**My question is how do I implement borrow trait/copy trait for an enum?**

I am using *rust-nightly-1.42.0 for i686-windows-pc with gnu-toolchain*

Comment: Please post the actual code in the question rather than a reference to it.

Comment: The question is unanswerable as it is: You should post an [MRE] reproducing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't take a copy on a string, but you can call `.clone()` on the object containing it.  That will solve the problem, but can potentially be expensive on memory since you now have two copies of the same thing.  Another approach is to use a smart pointer type like `Rc` to wrap it.  This way, when you clone it it will just increment the reference count of the smart pointer instead of actually cloning the whole object.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-00-smart-pointers.html